# armv6 / or lipo command error

Tags: binary, armv6

Hello Need some help please...
When I try to send my zip file in the application loader, I get an error that says I need armv6...so when I include armv6 in all the architectures I then get these errors...

Unable to run the lipo command /Applications/Xcode.app...: can't open input file: ...(No such file or directory)
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
The binary being analyzed must exist: ...

Been trying everything.  I'm using xcode 4.5.1  Thanks for any replies.

Comment: figured it out... don't worry about armv6 in the architectures... just change the deployment target to 4.3

Answer (score 2):

> figured it out... don't worry about armv6 in the architectures... just change the deployment target to 4.3 – Landon Oct 23 '12 at 0:47

This finally worked for me.  xCode defaults to building for 4.0, which can't run armv7, and if you change to armv6 the iTunes store won't validate it.  Changing to 4.3 was fine.